# Riemann Zeta Function for Negative Integers

Tags: complex-analysis

How is it possible that the Riemann zeta function of all negative integers is 0. And why is it that zeta of -1 is the only non-zero value (-1/12)?

Does anyone have a good and/or intuitive explanation for it?

Comment: John Baez's talk sheds some light on this, without much complex analysis. https://youtu.be/vzjbRhYjELo

Answer (score 1):

The riemann zeta function equals zero for all *even* negative integers. These are known as the trivial zeros. If you do not know the underlying theory of the Riemann Zeta function / analytic continuation, it will be very difficult to offer an "intuitive" explanation for why.

Comment: Could you tell me what a good source is for learning about this topic?

Comment: I wrote my master's thesis on this and many other aspects of the zeta function. http://thescholarship.ecu.edu/bitstream/handle/10342/4703/Molokach_ecu_0600O_11345.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y